# If object from UIViewController how get only the names of custom properties that I created (in run time)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, protocols, objective-c-runtime

I have implemented the following code in a view controller that is defined to conform to `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource`:

```
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(self, &outCount);

for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
    objc_property_t property = properties[i];
    const char *propName = property_getName(property);
    if(propName) {
        [properitiesList addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:propName]];
    }
}
```

When I do that, I see not only my custom properties, but also a few introduced by those protocols, namely: `hash`, `superclass`, `description` and `debugDescription`.

How do I show just the properties from my subclass, and not those introduced by those protocols?

Comment: i extend from UIViewController and 
i create property 
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *custome;
in the header 

when i print the properties of this class in run time give me this :

it print my custom property and other properties by apple 

i want only my property 
this is the output :
{(
    custom,
    superclass,
    hash,
    debugDescription,
    description,
)}

Comment: i want only my custom properties without apple properties  in array   {( custom)}

Comment: If you subclass, it will show the properties just for the subclass. When you say "extend", I assume you mean subclass? Perhaps you can update your question with a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yea when extend class  from NSObject 
it show only my custom properties but when i extend UIViewController or UITableViewCell appear other properties from apple

Comment: yea the problem because i set this   in header <UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource>
when i delete show only my custom properties

Comment: i try to put in <UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource> in .m class but show same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `class_copyPropertyList` method will only return properties declared for the class, not those declared for superclass. As the header for `class_copyPropertyList` says, it returns

> An array of pointers of type `objc_property_t` describing the properties declared by the class. Any properties declared by superclasses are not included.

But the issue is that you've defined your class to conform to `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate`. Thus properties introduced by those protocols *are* being interpreted as properties for your subclass, not for some superclass.

The simplest solution is to remove those protocol declarations and then the error goes away.

If you don't want to remove those protocol declarations (e.g. you want to still enjoy code completion for those protocol methods), you can create an abstract class that conforms to these protocols, and then subclass that. For example:

```
@interface AbstractViewControllerForCollectionView : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>
@end

@implementation AbstractViewControllerForCollectionView

// we have to implement the required methods; let's just warn the developer if they accidentally fail to subclass

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSAssert(FALSE, @"this must be subclassed");
    return 0;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSAssert(FALSE, @"this must be subclassed");
    return nil;
}

@end
```

And:

```
@interface ViewController : AbstractViewControllerForCollectionView

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myPropertyName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *objects;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;

    NSLog(@"%@", [[self class] properties]);
}

+ (NSArray *)properties {
    NSMutableArray *propertyList = [NSMutableArray array];

    unsigned int outCount, i;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(self, &outCount);
    for(i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        const char *propName = property_getName(property);
        if (propName) {
            [propertyList addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:propName]];
        }
    }
    free(properties);

    return propertyList;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.objects.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // configure cell

    return cell;
}
@end
```

The only downside here is that the compiler won't warn you if you fail to subclass the required methods. But at least you'll get a runtime failure/warning that describes the problem.

Comment: Yea or can use custom delegate and custom data source

Comment: i mean you can use do Separating for delegate and data source 
like 
@interface  SeparateDelegateDataSource : NSObject  <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>

Comment: Yep, that will do it, too, though that just transfers the problem of additional properties reported by `class_copyPropertyList` from your view controller to your datasource/delegate object. It depends upon what precisely you need `class_copyPropertyList` for. Personally, while I was initially enamored by the runtime functions, but I've since shied away from it because I found myself contorting myself (like above) to get the desired behavior. I guess it just depends upon why you need the runtime functions and you have to ask yourself whether the cure is worse than the disease.

Comment: I love use run time process because i feel like have magnetic power  this first time i use it But it some time hard :(